# Can 64-bit be dual booted with 32-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I'm currently running 64-bit Ubuntu on a computer that came with windows XP 32-bit. Is it possible to dual boot windows 32-bit with Ubuntu 64-bit?

Comment: Don't see the reason for the down-vote, maybe the person who did it might think dropping a comment would help us understand why is this not a good question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your computer has a CPU with 64bit instructions it does not mater what systems you have on your computer, they will not affect each other.

If your CPU has 64bit instructions you can run any 32 or 64 bit systems.

They wont interfere with each other.

Even tough you can install Windows after having Ubuntu installed already its much easier to install Windows and then after install Ubuntu since Ubuntu will configure dual boot for you but Windows will instead mess up your booting.

Comment: I have an AMD Athlon 64 X2 dual core processor so I think it should work thank you very much for your help!

Comment: True, gl and dont forget that Windows should not be installed after Linux (unless you want to repair Grub) but you soulg not have any problems installing Ubuntu after Windows (it will configure dual boot for you automatic).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help you must have read my mind that was the next question I had which to install first seen where it said that windows should be installed first, Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: Sorry I am new here and certainly did not mean to give a down vote if there is a way to remove it please explain and I will do it ASAP!!

Comment: You cannot down-vote your own questions :P Some other users when seeing Windows in a question will down-vote it automatically like if it was not a valid question or low quality, its good practice to leave a comment why the person thinks that it deserves the down-vote. Some one down-voted your question for no reason (silly) so I left a comment asking why. Its not you and the question is fine in my opinion. On the site you can up-vote questions and answers and down-vote questions an answer reflecting the quality and information on those questions and answers.

Comment: Alright great thanks for explaining that to me thought I did something wrong. :) thank you for all your help once again, Merry Christmas!!

Comment: You too Craig, have fun!

Comment: You need separate partitions for the 32-bit version and 64-bit version.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, should be no problem at all, the OS for the most part are independent of each other

Comment: I have looked up dual booting and it says to install windows first then reinstall Ubuntu is this what you would recommend?

Comment: It is easier that way. If you install Ubuntu, then windows, the windows boot loader will not boot ubuntu, so you need to re-install grub. It is easy enough to re-install grub, but not intuitive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows